# SSIS Parent Master Job Executed via SQL Agent vs Visual Studio

Tags: ssis

Here is the situation. We are upgrading many ssis packages from 2008R2 to a more up to date version. On the 2008R2 server this packages run flawlessly. But on the new server sometimes they hang (freeze) if they are executed via a SQL Agent. We believe that the reason is that there is a huge memory (RAM) difference between the two servers. Right now we are in the works for moving them to a very strong servers with lots of resources.

The thing is that I never experienced the hang (freeze) when I run the Parent Master Job within Visual Studio. Everything runs smooth. The Parent job consist of many "Execute Package" Tasks. As many know this task executes packages hosted on a SSIS server.

What I really need to understand is if there is any difference in terms of how resources are used.
Does visual studio uses the local machine resources to run the packages even if they are hosted in a remote SSIS server?

That will explain why I never experienced the issue before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you run packages in Visual Studio, the package is using the resources of the machine that is running visual studio...at least for the internal processes of running the packages.   When the package queries a table, that query uses the resources of the SQL Server where the table lives.

When you deploy the packages to SQL Server and execute them via a job, the package uses the resources of the SQL Server that it is deployed to.

Comment: So if the package loaded in visual studio have "Execute Package Tasks" pointing to dtsx pkgs on a remote ssis server. In this case the resources used for the remote pkg will be the ones on the remote SSIS server. Right?

This makes even harder to understand why the parent master package hangs when ran with SQL Agent vs Visual Studio. Makes zero sense.

Thanks

Comment: No, the Execute Package Task would get the .dtsx file from the remote server, but run it internally using the local computer as the engine that runs the package.

Comment: So that explains why I don't have freezing problems when I run the process on visual studio.That makes sense. Thanks Tab